# Maria DB change datadir on windows server

Tags: windows, mariadb, windows-server

I installed MariaDB on my windows server and saw it defaults the datadir where the databases are stored to `C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\data`

I wanted it moved the the E: disk that's dedicated to database stuff.

I thought copying the datadir and then modifying the my.ini in the `C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\data` datadir would solve it, but when I tried to restart the service it wouldn't start.
I also tried setting the folder permissions to network service but that didn't seem to help.

What do I have to do to move my datadir on windows?

Comment: This might not immediately help with your problem, but ability to diagnose what is happening is extremely important. That is : reading the error log, and if this still does not help, on Windows, looking at what mysqld.exe is doing using procmon. You need to know *why* the service does not start,  this will help tremendously to fix it.

Comment: Yea, funny thing is, there was nothing in the windows error log. There also wasn't a thing to find if there was a log file written somewhere. The docs say it should have entries in the windows error log but there wasn't. Only resolution I got when I finally found out the options to execute mysqld manuallywith the verbose options where it stated no permissions.   Thats how I got to the xcopy solution below.

Comment: There is MariaDB error log, a file in the datadir with the extension .err. If it is not there, then there is a Windows *event* log, where messages are written. If it is not there, for example the service is configuration is broken, and mysqld.exe is not there, then there is procmon to find that out,

Comment: oh, hey windows thanks for hiding the extensions. Now that you pointed out  the location of the file I can see it now. It has COMPUTERNAME.err as filename

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of searching I stumbled across http://baazgusht.blogspot.nl/2017/02/change-datadir-of-mariadb-in-window.html

It gave me the hint I needed to move the datadir  on windows.

- open cmd in administrator mode(start search cmd, rightlick execute as administrator)
- type `Net stop MariaDB` (or whatever you named your service. for me it was `net stop "MariaDB 10_2_7"`
- CD to `C:\program files\mariadb 10.2\`(or wherever your mariadb is installed)
- Type:  `xcopy data E:\MariaDB /O /X /E /H /K` *(E:\MariaDb is my location, you may have another location. replace E:\MariaDB with whatever you want, just use the same value below for the datadir in my.ini)*
- Xcopy will ask when the destination doesn't exist if it should be a file or a folder. Choose the option that represents Folder.
- Type: notepad data/my.ini
- change the value of `datadir=C:\Pro....` to `datadir=E:\MariaDB`
- save (ctrl + s)
- in CMD type `net start mariadb` (or whatever you named your service. for me it was `net start "MariaDB 10_2_7"`

Answer (score 2):

I think that real problem is this one.

MariaDB use MySQL5.5 (or MariaDB10 for other version I use) as "group user" to set full permission on data folder. But this "group user" is not create under Windows "users and groups". So you cannot add this group on security tab and set permission to another folder.

Effectively, the workaround is to xcopy the original data folder to new location preserving the original permission.

But my problem is that I recover after a crash an older data folder. So it's not clear that workaround work (I wil try it tonight). I need to set the correct user group.

A true bug fix: fix intallation of MariaDB to effectivily create the "group user" in right place not just use it in folder permission.

Answer (score 1):

Additional information to @Tschallacka's answer:

The copied my.ini file should be deleted from the target directory ("E:\MariaDb" in their example), since it is not honored by MariaDB. (It still contains the old path anyways.) And the contents of the source directory ("C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\data" in their example) except my.ini should be deleted too, since those files are now found at the new path.

@Tschallacka's solution works because xcopy also copies permissions of the files. Windows Explorer does not.

Explanation of the options for xcopy:
`/E Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.`
`/H Copies hidden and system files also.`
`/K Copies attributes. Normal Xcopy will reset read-only attributes.`
There are no hidden, system or read-only files in there right after install and there shouldn't after normal use and it shouldn't matter for the copied files, but it won't hurt.
`/O Copies file ownership and ACL information.`
The original directory has some additional permissions set. Without those, the MariaDB service seems to not be able to access the copied files properly.
`/X Copies file audit settings (implies /O).`
The service seems to start fine even without this option.

Answer (score 0):

AS the issue is based on the fact that the standard account under which the service runs doesn't have any privileges you could also fix that to make it work.

You can go to Services and change the "Log On As" to something that has the privilege to access the server.
Switching it to e.g. "Local System" worked for me with just copying the files.
A cleaner approach would be to run the service using an account that is in an appropriate group to access the files, maintaining the ability to do proper access control in your system.

For sure you still need to change the entry for "datadir=..." in the data/my.ini location to point to your new location.

Using xcopy carries the risk that the underlying security rules for "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" and "ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES" basically translate to the group "Everyone" if you use functionalities like icals to load the safe and restore the privileges from the original folder.
Based on your use-case hat is something you might or might not accept.

Answer (score -1):

After some confusion with this error I can recommend that you:

1. Use slashes in Windows paths, for example `C:/MariaDB/DB`.
2. Experiment with adequate permissions. This seems to work:

   ```
   cacls Path_to_MariaDB_DBData /E /T /P "Network Service":F
   ```